# How do I preload an association in rails based on a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to preload an association, say you have `Posts` and `subscribers`.

I want to preload all posts where the current user is a `subscriber`, but at the same time, preload all the `subscribers` as well.

The query I am using is like this:

```
Post.includes(:subscribers)
    .references(:subscribers)
    .where(subscribers: { id: current_user.id })
```

This gives me the correct list of `posts` but does not give me all the `subscribers` for each `post`, just the current user. Is there a way to get all the `subscribers` while at the same time scope it to only posts that I can see as a subscriber?

Comment: Do you really want to check whether subscribers.id == current_user.id. Is this query really useful? `where(subscribers: { id: current_user.id })` I think you want `where(subscribers: { user_id: current_user.id })`

Comment: @dnsh This is actually a has_many :subscribers, through: :subscriptions

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Post.includes(:subscribers).where(id: Post.joins(:subscribers).where(subscribers: {id: current_user.id}).select(:id))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well, just wondering if there's a more performant way than doing 2 separate queries.